# IText 7 Link Border Showing

Tags: itext7

Using Itext 7 for generating pdf and found Anchor tag is deprecated hence used Link.

```
Link projectNameLink = new Link("**Test**", PdfAction.createURI("https://www.google.com"));       
projectNameLink.setFontColor(Color.BLUE)
               .setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
Paragraph footerContent = new Paragraph().add(projectNameLink).setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
```

Added this to paragraph. The document in Acrobat Reader shows border around **Test**. Same thing I see in the below Url . Is it a bug ? Or am missing something.  How to remove the border ?

[Try to download the file](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/highlevel/cmpfiles/chapter04/cmp_jekyll_hyde_overviewV1.pdf)

And open in Acrobat Reader on can see borders along the Link Text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour for iText is to add the border.
You can however apply some style to these actions.

```
PdfAnnotation la1 = new PdfLinkAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0))
        .setHighlightMode(PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT)
        .setAction(js)
        .setBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_UNDERLINE); // this is what you need
```

Have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples/chapter-6

Comment: Worked. Better than getting a round rectangle Border around Text I prefer the under line. My actual requirement was without even an Under line just a blue colored Text but I guess I can live with this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then please mark your question as solved, and my answer as the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just wanting to have no border at all, and I've found the solution:

```
PdfAnnotation la1 = new PdfLinkAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0))
    .setHighlightMode(PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE)
    .setAction(js)
    .setBorder(new PdfArray(new int[]{0,0,0}))
```

I found out the solution reading the javadoc: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/annot/PdfAnnotation.html#getBorder--