# itex7: Add link to PDF without border or underline

Tags: c#, itext7

I want to add a link to a document without underline or border.

Based on the documentation I expected the first example below to result in no border around the link. That did not work so I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938575/itext-7-link-border-showing) which I adapted to the second example. Using this method I am able to replace the border with an underline, but not to get rid of both.

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("links.pdf"));
Document d = new Document(pdfDoc);

// example 1
Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
  .Add(new Link("Link with border", PdfAction.CreateURI("http://www.google.com")).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER))
  .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER); // no border on the paragraph   
d.Add(p);

// example 2
PdfLinkAnnotation linkA = new PdfLinkAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));
linkA.SetHighlightMode(PdfLinkAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);    
//This would give underline instead of borders
//linkA.SetBorderStyle(PdfLinkAnnotation.STYLE_UNDERLINE);     
linkA.SetAction(PdfAction.CreateURI("http://www.google.com"));
Link link = new Link("Please no borders", linkA);   
d.Add(new Paragraph(link));

pdfDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get no borders in your second example you need to specify borders via `PdfLinkAnnotation#SetBorder(PdfAnnotationBorder)` method instead of the `SetBorderStyle`.

Here is a code snippet of yours slightly modified example:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("links.pdf"));
Document d = new Document(pdfDoc);


Link link = new Link("Please no borders", PdfAction.CreateURI("http://www.google.com"));
link.GetLinkAnnotation().SetBorder(new PdfAnnotationBorder(0, 0, 0));     

d.Add(new Paragraph(link));

pdfDoc.Close();
```

You can find more info about this method call in javadocs: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/annot/PdfAnnotation.html#getBorder--

## Some background

By default iText doesn't specify any specific border properties for link annotations. And as per PDF specification default value for annotations is to have borders:

> ## ISO32000-1 12.5.2 "Annotation Dictionaries" Table 164 – "Entries common to all annotation dictionaries":
>
> Border - An array specifying the characteristics of the annotation’s border, which shall be drawn as a rounded rectangle.
> The array consists of three numbers defining the horizontal corner radius, vertical corner radius, and border width, all in default user space units. If the corner radii are 0, the border has square (not rounded) corners; if the border width is 0, no border is drawn.
>
> [...]
>
> Default value: [0 0 1].